# Sorting algorithm not displaying correct output

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, shellsort

I don't understand why I am not getting correct output from my shell sorting algorithm, I cannot identify the problem, any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
public class sortingExample {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] myArray = {4, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2};
    int increments = (myArray.length/2), i, tmp, j;
    for(; increments > 0; increments /= 2) {
        for(i = increments; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            j = i - increments;
            tmp = myArray[j];
            if(myArray[j] > myArray[i]) {
               myArray[j] = myArray[i];
               myArray[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(myArray[0]);
}
```

It should return the smallest number but instead no change is occurring, all the numbers remain in their corresponding positions.

Comment: You have `myArray[j] = myArray[i];` immediately followed by `myArray[j] = tmp;`. Is that really what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you swap implementation inside if-statement. You have set the same element in your array twice with j as index.

```
tmp = myArray[j];
if(myArray[j] > myArray[i]) {
    myArray[j] = myArray[i];           
    myArray[i] = tmp; //here you have to set a tmp value for i-element to swap two values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can improve your code with above answers. But if you need to get the min value from array with minimum lines of code you can follow below example :

```
System.out.println("min Value - " + Arrays.stream(myArray).summaryStatistics().getMin());
System.out.println("max Value - " + Arrays.stream(myArray).summaryStatistics().getMax());
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of  `myArray[j] = tmp;` you should have `myArray[i] = tmp;`